# IntelliJ Mac - LESS Compiling with Autoprefixer

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, compilation, less, autoprefixer

I was using a file watcher in IntelliJ which automatically compiled my less files into css files. I added an argument to the file watcher which used the autoprefix plugin to add all the prefixes to the compiled css file.

I now switched from a windows machine to mac and I can't get it to work like this there. I installed the autoprefix plugin via npm: https://github.com/less/less-plugin-autoprefix
And I set everything like it was on my windows machine: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000659610-Autoprefixer-in-file-watcher

But now I only get the error message:

> "Unable to load plugin autoprefix please make sure that it is
>   installed under or at the same level as less"

Same error occurs when calling the compiling with plugin from the command line. LESS compiling itself is working fine.

Does anyone has an idea what I'm missing? I'm pretty new on Mac so I don't know if I miss some environment variables or something? Or how can I check where the plugin is installed and where do I have to install it?

Comment: should work just in the same way as on Windows. Do you have both `less` and `less-plugin-autoprefix` installed globally? What plugin versions do you use?

Comment: Yes, I installed both of the plugins with "-g" parameter.
This are the installed versions: "less@3.0.1" "less-plugin-autoprefix@1.5.1"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to an answer which seems to has been deleted in the meantime I found the solution.
The current autoprefix plugin needs an older version of less. It's not compatible with less 3.0.1.

After uninstalling less and installing version 2.7.3 with

```
npm install -g less@2.7.3
```

it is working again.

Found the solution here: https://github.com/less/less-plugin-autoprefix/issues/30